# One column left and one center

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to make a page which contains a column of 330px width at left and then an other column of 670px max-width that is centered at the remaining width of the page. Of course if screen width is too small to fit 1000px, the second column will be resized. How do I do that?

This is my current CSS Code:

```
#left {
   float:left;
   width:330px;
}
#right {
   ???
}
```

Comment: what browsers are you looking for this to work in? does it have to work in IE7?

Comment: Nope, no IE at all. Just modern browsers

Comment: While the comment made me laugh, IE10 is in many respects a more modern browser than Firefox.

Comment: Well, with the exception of that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do this without `calc` or other nasty overly modern hacking. The following should even work fine in IE7, not sure about IE6 and its respect for `margin:0 auto` in nested elements but could even work:

### HTML

```
<div id="layout">
    <div id="leftcolumn">
        Test
    </div>
    <div id="remainder">
        <div id="rightcolumn">
            Test
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

### CSS

```
div {
    color:white;
    height:400px;  
    text-align:center;
}
#leftcolumn {
    background:red;
    float:left;
    width:120px;
}
#remainder {
    margin-left:120px;
}
#rightcolumn {   
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    max-width:300px;
    background:green;
}
```

[Fiddle supplied](http://jsfiddle.net/PtkBs/).

Comment: What is not 'perfectly' aligned about this? It's spot on centered and will always be. Resize the result pane on the fiddle to see this for yourself. If you are confused about the `margin-left:120px` - that corresponds to the width of the left column for exactly the purpose of perfect centering.

Comment: Sorry, I did that but forgot to remove my comment!